# Do we want hats during Winter Bash 2016?

Tags: discussion

As we say goodbye to 2016 and look ahead to the holiday season and 2017, there's one last event to get through: Winter Bash!

> The year is rapidly coming to a close, which means even though we typically [hate it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/268583#268583), it’s time to have some fun...with hats!  That’s right - **it’s time for Winter Bash 2016!!**
>
> **Overview**
>
> Most of you remember previous years’ events, but here is a quick little reminder. Winter Bash is an annual event that can run on any Stack Exchange site that chooses to participate. Users have fun by earning “hats” for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (very similar to badges). We track everyone’s progress using hats in a leaderboard that looks similar to this:
>
> [image: Winter Bash 2016 Leaderboard]
>
> As always, we’re coming up with new hat designs for this year’s fun!
>
> **The Details**
>
> The event will run from **19 December 2016** up to and including **08 January 2017**. Users will be able to see all the hats they’ve earned on http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com. That site will also have a landing page, explaining the rules and other details of the event.
>
> Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. And just like last time, **at the end of the event, all hats will go back into storage.**
>
> The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

Last year, we decided to join Stack Exchange sites everywhere for Winter Bash, and if memory serves, it was pretty successful. We had some pretty impressive hat totals.

Do we want to do this again in 2016?

Answer (score 9):

## DEFINITELY

Why not anyway?

Hat's are like badges. (mostly) They're fun, and some will somewhat help the community- thinking more of Hat Trick (hit rep cap) and Explorer (greet a new user by editing and upvoting a post), both are good.

And it's fun (for me).

So why not?

Comment: It's not for me, personally, but I'm not opposed to it. If it helps with the community, great! If it brings some levity to the site, even better!